# Adaptive streaming to rtsp relay

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I have a camera at `/dev/video4` under linux, and I want to stream this to a `mediamtx` server.

I am able to do that locally using ffmeg with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -re -i /dev/video4 -f rtsp -rtsp_transport udp -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -c:v h264_vaapi -vf 'format=nv12,hwupload' -b:v 5000k -b:a 128k -c:a aac rtsp://user:pass@host:8554/live/fly
```

It works well on a local network.

Now my problem is that this computer will be in a car connected to a 4G/5G gateway, and the bandwidth will vary a lot, from less than 1Mbit/s to 50Mbit/s upload (roughly).

I am looking for a solution that will measure the available bandwidth, like every 10 seconds or so and automatically adapt the bitrate.

A few info:

- Ultimately I want to show the feed in OBS, I use mediamtx which works, but I can deploy something else
- The relay server (running mediamtx) has a public ipv4 and ipv6 I fully control, so no NAT on this side
- It is fine if the live cut for a few seconds and restart with the new bitrate, it doesn't have to be fully "on the fly".
- I'm open to any tool, I know gstreamer can be more flexible

Comment: What research have you done regarding specifying the bitrate using ffmpeg?

Comment: Most of what I find when searching for this, is variable bit rate at the codec level, which is absolutely not what I want. The other resource I found was for a server to stream multiple qualities and select one depending on bandwidth, but again, not what I want.

Comment: That information needs to be in your question body. Also, there's several questions on this site and its sisters that I found with a quick web search that appear relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65852931/ffmpeg-keeping-quality-when-reducing-fps-and-streaming-over-rtsp-with-rtsp-simpl

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using `gstreamer`.

The `mediamtx` server can be used as is and it's `whip` endpoint should be used.

The on the client:

```
gst-launch-1.0 whipclientsink signaller::whip-endpoint="http://user:pass@example.com:8889/live/fly/whip" name=ws \
  v4l2src device=/dev/video4 ! ws.
```

This require the following plugin:

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-rs/-/tree/main/net/webrtc?ref_type=heads

This `webrtc` plugin handle adaptive encoding and congestion control.

Answer (score 0):

The -b:v argument specifies the video bitrate. You will adjust this value to meet your network's needs.

See this answer on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/65884523/704977

Comment: I know that. I want adaptive bitrate. Basically monitoring the connection, measuring the bandwidth, and set the -b:v and -v:a parameters automatically.